# Android App error "Unfortunately has stopped working"

Tags: android

So I was able to successfully create a main popup that calls other popups. I got the first popup to work great but for some reason the second popup isn't working. I copied and pasted the first one over and it worked great. I then added all of my code minus the xml doc and it worked again. Finally when I changed the layout it doesn't work =/. Not sure where else to look or try. Here is the layout call and the error code. Thanks!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.arrestee_popup);
```

Here are the logs

```
03-18 15:48:24.353 18979-18979/com.f0xcr4f7.intelwatch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.f0xcr4f7.intelwatch, PID: 18979
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.f0xcr4f7.intelwatch/com.f0xcr4f7.intelwatch.ArresteePop}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
  at com.f0xcr4f7.intelwatch.ArresteePop.onCreate(ArresteePop.java:89)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: You have a error NullPointerException, you try to occupy object in Null, verify using debug.
Maybe you button is null.

Comment: post your `xml` code

Answer (score 0):

> when I changed the layout it doesn't work

Because `findViewById(R.id.your_button)` will return null if you didn't include `@+id/your_button` into `arrestee_popup.xml`.

And consequently, `yourButton.setOnClickListener` throws a `NullPointerException`

Comment: I have an activity with the button (arrestee information) and should activate the pop up for arrestee.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error with my save and cancel buttons in the arrestee class.. The error made it seem like it was in the xml which was miss leading =/.

```
    cancelArrestee_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancelArrestee);
    saveArrestee_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSaveArrestee);
```